# Why my gradient descent algorithm for linear regression diverges

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Gradient descent for linear regression diverges even if I decrease the value for alpha or even delete it!

```
def gradientDescent(sqft_living, price, theta, alpha, num_iters):
m = price.size

# make a copy of theta, to avoid changing the original array, since numpy arrays
# are passed by reference to functions
theta = theta.copy()

J_history = [] # Use a python list to save cost in every iteration
theta_history = []
for z in range(num_iters):
    term = 0
    term0 = 0        
    for i in range(m):
        h = np.dot(theta, sqft_living[i])
        term += (h - price[i]) 
        term0 += term * sqft_living[i][0]
    temp0 = theta[0] - alpha * (1/m) * term0


    term = 0
    term1 = 0
    for i in range(m):
        h = np.dot(theta, sqft_living[i])
        term += (h - price[i])
        term1 += term * sqft_living[i][1]
    temp1 = theta[1] - alpha * (1/m) * term1

    theta[0] = temp0
    theta[1] = temp1


    cost = computeCost(sqft_living, price, theta)
    print(cost)
    J_history.append(cost)

    theta_history.append(theta)
 
return theta, J_history
```

This is the using of the algorithm

```
# initialize fitting parameters
theta = np.zeros(2)

# some gradient descent settings
iterations = 100
alpha = 0.00001

theta, J_history = gradientDescent(sqft_living, price, theta, alpha, iterations)
print(J_history)
```

This is a part of the output :

cost =  3.8144815615142405e+22

cost =  8.337226954930875e+33

cost =  1.8222489338606256e+45

cost =  3.982848487760674e+56

cost =  8.705222311669148e+67

cost =  1.9026808508648173e+79

cost =  4.158646718757122e+90

cost =  9.089460549082665e+101

cost =  1.9866629377457605e+113

cost =  4.342204476162054e+124

cost =  9.49065860875058e+135

cost =  2.074351894810886e+147

cost =  4.533864256311113e+158

Comment: Can you also give the code for  computeCost method in your question?